# WARN : No transform between frames /map and scanmatcher_frame available

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I'm trying to map any unknown environment using HECTOR Slam with RPLidar alone. I run Hector Slam node in one terminal and also launched RPlidar node in another. But unable to get the map due to the following warning :

```
[WARN] [1459701587.170837560]: No transform between frames /map and scanmatcher_frame available after 20.001770 seconds of waiting.
```

I'm unable to figure out how to rectify the problem, as I'm new to ROS. Could anyone pls help me out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230825/warn-:-no-transform-between-frames-/map-and-scanmatcher_frame-available./) by [Mohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26473/mohan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are probably missing the (static) transformation between the `/base_link` frame and RPLidar's frame.

See http://answers.ros.org/question/208584/hector-slam-does-not-work/

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26473/mohan/) on 2016-04-04**:
It worked. I'm able to get map, but distorted. I guess this might be due to not doing  pre processing on RPlidar raw scan data. Please correct me if I'm wrong and  Thank you very much for reply. Moreover If I move my RPlidar sometimes this error showup " searchDir angle change too large". Pls helpme

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-04-04**:
I think it'd be best to open a new question about this, Mohan. There, also post a screenshot of the "distorted" map; it will help with debugging. Finally, could you please mark my answer above as correct by clicking on the checkmark icon on the left? Thanks